# Error compiling grpc generated source

Tags: c++, grpc

Im running into some issues compiling both the example route_guide generated source as well as my own. Im sure that its user error but Im not sure where the issue is. The error seems to hint something with GRPC_FINAL which I wasn't able to find a reference to.

$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.0.0

```
./route_guide.grpc.pb.h:29:2: error: expected expression
 public:
 ^
./route_guide.grpc.pb.h:28:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'class RouteGuide'
class RouteGuide GRPC_FINAL {
             ^
./route_guide.grpc.pb.h:28:7: note: forward declaration of   'routeguide::RouteGuide'
class RouteGuide GRPC_FINAL {
  ^
route_guide.grpc.pb.cc:25:18: error: incomplete type 'routeguide::RouteGuide' named in nested name specifier
std::unique_ptr< RouteGuide::Stub> RouteGuide::NewStub(const std::shared_ptr< ::grpc::ChannelInterface>& channel, const ::grpc::StubOptions& options) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./route_guide.grpc.pb.h:28:7: note: forward declaration of       'routeguide::RouteGuide'
    class RouteGuide GRPC_FINAL {
```

Comment: I was able to get this to compile and link by defining GRPC_FINAL and GRPC_OVERRIDE `CPPFLAGS += -I $(INCLUDE_DIR) -I $(SRC_DIR) -I /usr/local/include -DGRPC_FINAL=final -DGRPC_OVERRIDE=override`. It would seem as though these would be included in a header somewhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling all of the grpc libs and headers and rebuilding from the v1.0.x branch.